# Azure firewall block System request, SQL Injection Attack: SQL Operator Detected

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

Some system request are blocked by Azure firewall if **Inspect request Body** is turn **ON** (recommended for system security).

Overview: 
I have a request to the system, I have a string parameter pass to the controller, but during submission firewall detected SQL operator like "<>.." characters on the string parameter. This caused the request block and response 403 forbidden error.

I was thinking below solutions, I shared this in this platform just hoping that someone has a better idea and solution.

1. Encode the string parameter to base-64, but my problem with this is that, I just bypass the firewall what if there is a serious hacking attack, it still not safe.
2. convert the string value to binary code, it will generate 1 and 0 values, same with solutions not safe.
3. limit user to input special characters on the field., the cons, is that it will limit the user.

If anyone out there has a better idea that would be of great help.
thank you.

Comment: So are the characters _actually_ SQL operators? Or do they just look like it? What's the actual reason reported by the Azure Firewall?

Comment: Hi Nick, they just look like SQL operators.

Comment: this is the logs from azure:Warning. Pattern match "(?i:(\\!\\=|\\&\\&|\\|\\||>>|<<|>=|<=|<>|<=>|\\bxor\\b|\\brlike\\b|\\bregexp\\b|\\bisnull\\b)|(?:not\\s+between\\s+0\\s+and)|(?:is\\s+null)|(like\\s+null)|(?:(?:^|\\W)in[+\\s]*\\([\\s\\d\"]+[^()]*\\))|(?:\\bxor\\b|<>|rlike(?:\\s+binary)?)|(?:regexp\\s+" at field.

Comment: Is the request sent via HTTP? How about URL Encode it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you well but the parameter is pass as a model to the controller not in the query string.